# Starting CCAction at particular time

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to start InFinite CCAction at particular time. I tried using CCSequence but it supports only finite time animation.

Any idea?

Best Regards,
Paras

Answer (score 1):

Put the action that you want to repeat inside of a method.  Then put this in your init method

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(myMethod) forTarget:self interval:10 paused:NO];
```

This will call myMethod after 10 seconds, however once inside myMethod you'll want to unschedule it.  So my method should look something like this.

```
- (void) myMethod
{
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleSelector:@selector(myMethod) forTarget:self];
    CCMoveBy *move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(75,0)];
    CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:move];
    [mySprite runAction:repeat];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines are what you need.

```
CCMoveBy* move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(75,0)];
CCCallFuncO* shot = [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(shoot:) object:enemy];
CCSequence* sequ = [CCSequence actions:move,shot,nil];
CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequ];
[sprite runAction:repeat]; //sprite here
```

Comment: Well that will not work. Let me try to give an example. Suppose there are 2 actions only. 1. Delay Action (for starting delay in the scene that I want to give) 2. Jump Action (that I want to repeat once the delay time is over). If I go by your approach then delay will also repeat. :) We need think another solution.

Comment: @Gabe That infinite loop will freeze the game

Comment: @paras mendiratta my advice, don't use actions just update the x and y coordinates inside a ccTime function.